# change permissions on external hd

Tags: permissions

I use ubuntu 14.04 and I formatted the external hd with a mac (exFat);
trying to change owner with: sudo chown root /media/marco/ubuntu

but I get this message: chown: changing ownership of ‘/media/marco/ubuntu’: Function not implemented

Suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

exFAT, like FAT and NTFS, are native Windows disk formats and so are not aligned with Linux permission system. They don't receive flags for Owner like a EXT3 or 4, so you can't "chown" a file system with exFAT, FAT or NTFS.

Comment: thanks diegov. I'm triying to format an external hd, I want to use it as a back up disk for Deja Dup. Should I format it ext4? If so, how? Using default Disks utility returns an error: Error synchronizing after initial wipe: Timed out waiting for object (udisks-error-quark, 0)

Comment: Déjà Dup are going to use it as a local disk, mounted by the OS, so for it there's no big difference. You can go with EXT4, as it will be OK for you to store large files. The drawback is that EXT4 will be harder to open in other OSes. About the Disk Utility problem, I suggest you to use GParted as it will give you more options. Once in GParted, try first to exclude all partitions of the disk prior them creating it again and formating it. If needed, disconnect/reconnect the disk after excluding the partition to assure the syncing.